# How to create breakpad symbols?

Tags: symbols, debug-symbols, google-breakpad

I run a [mini-breakpad-server](https://github.com/electron/mini-breakpad-server) on my server and it's collecting the reports correctly from my `Electron` app, however I don't know how to create breakpad symbols (for windows, OSX, Linux) to work with my Electron app, could you give me a hint please?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't work with mini-breakpad-server before,
But I do use breakpad for the crash tracking in our game project with a simple breakpad server coded by ourself.

Basically, 
on the client side, what you need to do is integrate breakpad client LIB to handle any exception, as the result of this step, you will get a "crash report file".
Then you will need to send the report to breakpad server by yourself. ( I think breakpad lib has some helper class for uploading the report)

If I remember correctly, on the server side, you will need to use a tool provided by breakpad to convert PDB to breakpad symbol.
Then use those symbol with other tool to generate callstack from client side "crash report file"

You could read some detail form this link:
http://zxstudio.org/blog/2014/10/28/integrating-google-breakpad/